Superset: error saving charts or dashboard
I have just installed Superset on a brand new machine over Docker and everything works fine but I can't save a chart or dashboard. I always get "Unable to save slice" error message.
I can save queries and datasources though without problem and if I access to a chart though a permalink I can see the chart as it was with not problem.
Going through the logs, I saw that the error message is:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)

The weird thing is that I'm not using sqlite3, but postgress...
The DB connection in the superset_config.py is (or I think it is):
# DB connection
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://XXX:XXX@postgres:5432/superset'
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True

I have confirmed that that's the config file set in  PATH SUPERSET_CONFIG_PATH=/app/superset_config.py
I have also confirmed that the postgres machine is running and is accesible from the superset machine.
Can anyone help to understand why is trying to connect to sqlite3?

Superset uses SQLite as its default database backend for metadata storage, which includes things like charts, dashboards, and other internal Superset information.
After setting SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in superset_config.py , you configured to use PostgreSQL for the metadata database by modifying the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI in superset_config.py to point to your PostgreSQL instance,
however, if there are remnants of SQLite usage (perhaps from a prior run or an incomplete configuration) or any other problem, Superset might still be trying to access the old SQLite file.
To resolve this, run superset db upgrade to apply all database migrations to your PostgreSQL instance and restart the Superset containers to ensure the new configuration is loaded..

Thanks, but it did not fix the issue. The installation is brand new, so I don't know where that "remnants of SQLite usage" could came from...

Apologies for the delay. To resolve the issue, please verify that the PostgreSQL database files and Superset configuration files have the correct read/write permissions. If issues persist, consider resetting Superset's metadata store to force it to use PostgreSQL from scratch.
If none of these steps succeed, try
cleeaning up any SQLite-related files in the .supersetdirectory or
reviewing the Docker configuration to ensure no outdated settings are being carried over.
